# How to share data through controller in Laravel using helpers?

Tags: php, laravel, session, helper

I am trying to use a helper to temporarily store a variable from one controller method to another controller method (of the same controller). I am doing this because I normally don't trust user input, as they could just pass a different ID through the form/URL and the function will run. Eventually, I want to use something like:

```
if (Context::getTale()->id === $tale->id) {
 // code here
}
```

To *get the Tale object*

My code:

```
class Context
{
    /**
     * Current tale.
     * @var Tale|null
     */
    protected static ?Tale $tale = null;

    /**
     * Get current tale.
     * @return Tale|null
     */
    public static function getTale(): ?Tale
    {
        return self::$tale;
    }

    /**
     * Set current tale.
     * @param Tale|null $tale
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setTale(?Tale $tale): void
    {
        if ($tale === null) {
            return;
        }

        self::$tale = $tale;
    }
}
```

I have registered the Context class in config/app.php under aliases.

In my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
 // stuff the controller does

 Context::setTale($tale)
}

public function saveProgress()
{
 // < Code to get the Tale from the DB using the id passed > 

 if (Context::getTale()->id === $tale->id) {
   // do something
 }
}
```

The problem is that every time I try to get the `$tale` from the context in `saveProgress` it returns null.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I could try and use a Session for this, but is that secure against user input? Is a user still able to edit the data from his/her browser?

Edit: Two methods are called and I want to use the same ID. I want this to check if the user is still reading the same tale (as I don't trust user input).

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a different ID"? Are 2 methods called and do you want both to use the same ID? Please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve, it seems like you are overthinking the way to do it.

Comment: Check setTale method - you cannot set tale in all cases - its always be null

Comment: @Luciano Will edit my question, thank you!

Comment: You controller instance will be created fresh on every request, so there won't be any retention of variables you've set. What you're looking to do would require you to set the value in a more persistent way. Something like a session variable or as a record linked to the user in the database. Why is it that you are adding this extra check? What does a potential 'bad actor' user gain by using a fake id?

Comment: @MattMcDonald nothing much really, he will only get his progress saved for a different tale...which is not a big disaster when come to think of it. You'd recommend a session variable? Is that secure enough so that the user won't be able to manipulate it from his/her own browser?

Comment: A session variable is secure in so much as it can't be manipulated by the user. But as you've stated that there isn't any risk if a user manipulates the value I'd probably recommend not implementing the check at all. Whenever it comes to designing systems there's always a trade-off between development complexity and benefit. In this case there seems very low benefit to adding this complexity. You also have to consider that it isn't just the complexity of coding this now, but as the system grows it's additional logic that needs to be maintained.